# Android: How to get a custom view to redraw partially?

Tags: android, drawing, partial, invalidation

I have a custom view that fills my entire screen. (A piano keyboard)
When a user touches the key, it causes `invalidate()` to be called and the whole keyboard gets redrawn to show the new state with a touched key.

Currently the view is very simple, but I plan to add a bit more nice graphics. Since the whole keyboard is dynamically rendered this would make redrawing the entire keyboard more expensive.

So I thought, let's look into partial redrawing. Now I call `invalidate(Rect dirty)` with the correct dirty region. I set my `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method to only draw the keys in the dirty region if I do indeed want a partial redraw. This results in those keys being drawn, but the rest of the keyboard is totally black/not drawn at all.

Am I wrong in expecting that calling `invalidate(Rect dirty)` would "cache" the current `canvas`, and only "allows" drawing in the dirty region?

Is there any way I can achieve what I want? (A way to "cache" the canvas and only redraw the dirty area?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Current nice workaround is to manually cache the full canvas to a bitmap:

```
 private void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
 {
     if (!initialDrawingIsPerformed)
     {
          this.cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888); //Change to lower bitmap config if possible.
          Canvas cacheCanvas = new Canvas(this.cachedBitmap);
          doInitialDrawing(cacheCanvas);
          canvas.drawBitmap(this.cachedBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
          initialDrawingIsPerformed = true;
     }
     else
     {
          canvas.drawBitmap(this.cachedBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
          doPartialRedraws(canvas);
     }
 }
```

Ofcourse, you need to store the info about what to redraw yourself and preferably not use a new `Paint` everytime, but that are details.

Also note: Bitmaps are quite heavy on the memory usage of your app. I had crashes when I cached a View that was used with a scroller and that was like 5 times the height of the device, since it used > 10MB memory!

Comment: Hmm, I don't like this solutnio because the reason his keys are partially drawn is because he should first have a full draw of hiscanvas anyway. The question is thus why his canvas didn't draw correctly in the first place.

Comment: I need to note that I now understand that when you call `invalidate` with a dirty `rect`, you can just use your normal drawing code, and it should only actually perform the drawing operations that are in the dirty `rect`. `Canvas` discards the operations that are outside the `rect`. Still, this means that a lot of your own code still renders and in my tests with HW acceleration on it was slower than just rendering the view fully.

Comment: Note that for drawing bitmaps to canvas the paint param can be null, e.g. `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null)`.

Answer (score 5):

To complement Peterdk's answer, you could save your operations in a Picture instead of a Bitmap.

- A Bitmap will save all pixels, like
  he said it could take a lot of
  memory.
- A Picture will save the
  calls, like drawRect, drawLine, etc.

It depends of what is really heavy in your application : a lot of draw operations, a few draw operations but controlled by heavy calculations, a lot of blank/unused space (prefer Picture) etc...

Comment: Excuse me. Will the `Picture` record `drawBitmap(bitmap)` calls? Probably no, right?

Comment: Note that Picture playback is only supported on software canvases, so you can't use Hardware layers for views that use this.