# How to partially redraw custom SurfaceView using separate thread without losing previous edits?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, surfaceview

I am currently having trouble with drawing to a custom `SurfaceView` from a thread that is not on my main UI. This `SurfaceView` takes up the entirety of the screen (Galaxy S3 in full screen) and must be updated from several sources.

The problem is that the custom `SurfaceView` will not save changes between updates to UI.

The custom `SurfaceView` class is defined within the activity that uses it, and the thread (let's call it `DrawingThread`) that runs periodic checks for updates is defined within the custom `SurfaceView` class. I have done this similar to [this tutorial](http://danielnadeau.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-canvas-beginners-tutorial.html).

Another external thread is updating a list of changes that must be made to the UI. `DrawingThread` checks this list every 50ms or so, and if the list is not empty, calculates a rectangle that must be redrawn.

```
// Thread waits for change request to UI or kill order
// Build Rect at point of Touch
try {
    Canvas = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(Rect); 
    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
        postInvalidate(); //Calls custom SurfaceView's onDraw() with the correct Canvas
    }
} finally {
    if (Canvas != null) {
        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas);
    }
}
// Loop
```

My `onDraw()` method for the custom `SurfaceView` is below:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Initialize vars for rectangle
    Paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    for (MapChanges change : ExternalClass.getMapChanges()) {
        // Build Rect at point of Touch
        // Select Color for Paint   
        canvas.drawRect(Rect, Paint);
        ExternalClass.removeMapChange(change); //Thread safe
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly except for the fact that it is forgetting changes from any previous `onDraw()` call. I am currently testing this by using an `OnTouchListener`.

Code procedure as I understand it:

- Touch adds a change request for the UI to the list in the `ExternalClass`.
- `DrawingThread` sees the list is no longer empty, safely grabs the Canvas, and `postInvalidates()` to call custom `SurfaceView`'s `onDraw()`.
- `onDraw()` updates the UI and removes the change request from `ExternalClass`.
- `DrawingThread` posts the `Canvas` and goes back to waiting.

My expected behavior is that I will accumulate dots on my screen with successive touches.  Instead, each touch clears the screen, leaving me with the background and exactly one dot where I last touched the screen.

I find this vastly confusing as `lockCanvas(Rect)` specifically mentions that it will save changes between locks by designating a "dirty" section. Google searches have lead me to believe that most users find the opposite problem: that they want the `View` redrawn but must do so every update manually.

Why is the program drawing a clean `SurfaceView` from scratch each UI update despite my designation of a "dirty" section to redraw?

No doubt someone will reference me to [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949036/android-how-to-get-a-custom-view-to-redraw-partially) where the programmer was advised to use bitmaps. I am trying to avoid this due to how new I am to this and my desire to not work with large amounts of memory (updating the UI is a tiny portion of my code). Working with simple shapes directly on a `View` would be ideal for me. Additionally it is presented as a workaround. Is this a flaw in the Android API?

Have been searching here and Google for several hours now. Hope I have not missed anything blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround by taking the `OnDraw()` out of the equation.  New `DrawingPanel` below:

```
class DrawingPanel extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Thread thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    private Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Random random;

    public DrawingPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    }

    @Override 
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) { 


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {          
        setWillNotDraw(false); //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()

        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            running = false;    //Tells thread to stop
            thread.join();      //Removes thread from mem.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        Rect myRect = new Rect();
        boolean firstRun = true;

        ChangeRequest ChangeReq;

        myPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        while(running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            canvas = null;

            ChangeReq = getUIChangeRequests();

            if (!ChangeReq.isEmpty() || (firstRun)) {                   
                if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    if (!firstRun) {  

                        // Calculate dirty space for editing
                        x = ChangeReq.getX();
                        y = ChangeReq.getY();

                        try {
                            myRect.set(x*RectSize, y*RectSize, x*RectSize + RectSize, y*RectSize + RectSize);
                            myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

                            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(myRect);

                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                // Draw
                                canvas.drawRect(myRect, myPaint);

                            }

                            // Remove ChangeRequest
                            ChangeReq.remove();

                        } finally {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            // Initialize canvas as all one color
                            myRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                            myPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);

                            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                //Draw
                                canvas.drawRect(myRect, myPaint); 
                            }

                            firstRun = false;
                        } finally {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This solves my drawing problem but brings up an interesting question of why I must initialize using `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();` and only then am able to draw using `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(Rect);`  I will ask this in another question.