# how to draw custom view partially?

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that fills the entire screen with the spider web and some letters on it, which will be same for one game .

The thing only change is the swipe curve to draw this curve i am calling the invalidate() which redraws every thing again and again.
 i want only swipe to be drawn .

Is there any way to do it please help me .

```
Path path = new Path();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Point point : points){
        if(first){
            first = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);

        }
        else{
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, Pswipe);
    invalidate();
```

Comment: Look out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949036/android-how-to-get-a-custom-view-to-redraw-partially

Comment: @shylendra i tried that but adding bitmap again and again on the canvas is too expensive .