# One large View or an array of smaller views

Tags: android, performance

My app needs a display with repeating pattern. Think a chess board where pieces can move within a square but not from one square to the next. Each cell is independent from the others. Each cell has a fixed size. Larger displays accommodate more cells. A typical screen might have one or two hundred of these cells.

Each cell can be an independent Java object, so my initial idea it to make a `View` subclass for the cell and pack them into a `ViewGroup`. On the other hand, the cells don't really play the Android layout game in the sense that they have a fixed size in pixels and cannot grow or shrink their size to accommodate different layouts. From this PoV, it makes sense to make one big `View` that can draw all of these cells. The `CellArray` view can then grow and shrink as the layout engine requests.

Which approach seems more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CellArray`. Not because it's "more natural" (I'm not sure what that means) but for technical reasons. Views in Android are pretty heavy-weight objects and having a couple of hundred views in your activity will not be easy for the system to handle. (The [Android lint rule for `TooManyViews`](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) will complain if it detects that your view count for a layout exceeds `ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT`, which defaults to 80. You can ignore lint warnings, but they usually are there for good reasons.)

Comment: Does it matter if only a small number of cells need to redraw themselves on every update? Once big `CellArray` would need to redraw the whole screen every time.

Comment: @iter - When you need to draw only a portion of the overall view, you can invalidate a particular rectangle and then in `onDraw` call `getClipBounds` to find what part or parts need to actually be drawn. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949036/android-how-to-get-a-custom-view-to-redraw-partially) for an example and some other ideas.